# Code to launch an app from a given list in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

If I have a list of apps installed on the Android device, how can I let the user choose one from the list and launch it (like when open a pdf file, the device will ask you which app do you want to use to open it).

Thanks,

Comment: Is this some arbitrary list of apps, or something like your example (e.g. a list of apps that can handle a specific file type)?

Comment: it will be better if there is a solution for an arbitrary list, otherwise an example like launch an email/chat app would also be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about your question. But in case open pdf file , you can add action.VIEW in your manifest:

```
    <application>
        <activity ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Now, when you choose a pdf in list file, your application will be in the list of applications that can open pdf files

Hope this helps you

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe the problem clear enough. What I want is to let the user choose one app (in a given list) to launch from my app. Thanks,